# Teams: Do you plan a report page with statistics?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-for-teams

For admin users it would be create to have a report page with statistics like at least

- Number of questions (ok, this is obvious)
- Number of answers
- Number of votes
- Number of comments
- Number of users
- User activity (new questions, answers, comments, votes)

As an admin I've to report the "success" of the project to my manager to somehow proof the ROI (return on investment). This is difficult at the moment.

Comment: This data will be appreciated. I'm about to use selenium, tampermonkey o js to get this data :b